# how do you break a reference

Tags: php

How do you break a reference to a variable in PHP without destroying the variable itself?

I have written a PHP loop that stores a reference to objects in `$GLOBALS['parent_variables']` and then destroy it at the end of the function.

The function is called in the loop. I assume I use:

```
unset($GLOBALS['parent_variables'])
```

Does that destroy the reference? Just to confirm...

I set the reference like this:

```
$GLOBALS['parent_variables'] = &$question->variables;
```

Comment: What do you mean with `reference`?

Comment: Hi, Here is an example: $GLOBALS['parent_variables'] = &$question->variables; How do I empty the reference in the $GLOBALS['parent_variables']

Comment: So you want that `$GLOBALS['parent_variables']` is still set, but it's empty or do you want to unset `$GLOBALS['parent_variables']`?

Comment: I want to unset it without destroying what is in $question->variables because if I do this at the end of the function in the loop: $GLOBALS['parent_variables'] The variable in $question->variables is destroyed as well. I need to check whether $GLOBALS['parent_variables'] is empty at some point and just move on.

Comment: @user3072613 Then don't reference it.

Comment: @Rahil Wazir I just want to remove the link between the $GLOBALS['parent_variables'] and $question->variables I want to still have the content in $question->variables

Comment: @Rahil Wazir I am using $GLOBALS['parent_variables'] as a temporary container. I need to store temporary data that can be accessed by other functions. I have to make sure that no old data is used. So I need to empty it after each process.

Comment: why don't you try it and see what happens?

Comment: unset() seems to work fine. I just wanted to confirm it.

Answer (score 0):

Unsetting from the array does only remove the 'reference' and does not change the original object you copied from. Example:

```
<?php

$foo = new StdClass();
$foo->bar = "hello";
$_FAKE_GLOBAL_ARRAY = array();
$_FAKE_GLOBAL_ARRAY['foo'] = $foo->bar;
echo "array references ".$_FAKE_GLOBAL_ARRAY['foo'];
echo "<br>object contains ".$foo->bar;
unset($_FAKE_GLOBAL_ARRAY['foo']);
echo "<br>now array references ".(isset($_FAKE_GLOBAL_ARRAY['foo']) ? $_FAKE_GLOBAL_ARRAY['foo'] : " nothing");
echo "<br>now object contains ".$foo->bar;
?>
```

outputs

```
array references hello
object contains hello
now array references nothing
now object contains hello
```

Answer (score -1):

After:

```
$GLOBALS['parent_variables'] = &$question->variables;
```

Using:

```
unset($GLOBALS['parent_variables'])
```

... will break the reference -- as in set `$parent_variables` to null, while keeping `$question->variables`.

Using:

```
$GLOBALS['parent_variables'] = null
```

... will set both variables to null.

Example:

```
$foo = 'bar';

$GLOBALS['baz'] = &$foo;
unset($GLOBALS['baz']);
var_dump($GLOBALS['baz'], $foo);  # null, bar; undefined index notice for baz

$GLOBALS['baz'] = &$foo;
$GLOBALS['baz'] = null;
var_dump($GLOBALS['baz'], $foo);  # null, null; no notice (since baz is set)
```